# Is a matrix equivalent with its row reduced one?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I manage to reduce a matrix A to the identity one, does that mean that I can actually use  it on any given equation instead?

$$AB = 0 \implies IB = 0\;\;?$$

Comment: Well, you can multiply by $A^{-1}$ and the resulting equation is equivalent to the original. In above case the answer is "Yes".

Comment: In general, the answer is no.

Comment: If $A$ reduces to anything besides the identity, or if the right side of the equation is something other than $0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "reduce a matrix $A$ to the identity"?

Comment: But why is that? The linear system that is being represented by the matrix is exactly the same whether the matrix is reduced or not.

Comment: If that were the case, then $Ax = b$ would always have the solution $x = b$, so long as $A$ could be reduced to the identity.  This is demonstrably not the case.  No, the linear system being represented is not "exactly the same".

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis I assume that "reducing $A$" refers to row-reduction, i.e. Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: In fact, if the right side is $0$, then you can indeed "replace $A$" with its row-equivalent version.  That is, $A$ will always have the same null-space (kernel) as its row-equivalent form.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom But in case I have a matrix that it reduces to the identity, can I not use it instead, even if my right side is not zero (given that the inverse of the indentity is itself)?

Comment: @PanagiotisFilianos see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A row-reduced matrix is row-equivalent to the original matrix, but not equal to it.

In your example, if you are able to row reduce a matrix $A$ to obtain the identity matrix, it is ***invertible***, and non-zero. So in you example, you CAN conclude that $$AB = {\bf 0} \iff A^{-1}AB = A^{-1}{\bf 0} \implies B = {\bf 0}$$.

**ADDED:** What *is* true is that a *system of equations*, when represented by an augmented coefficient matrix, and then row-reduced using Gaussian Elimination, the row reduced system of equations is equivalent to the original system of equations. Any solution  to the system of equations represented by the row reduced matrix is a solution to the original system of equations. But a square matrix, in and of itself, does not represent a system of equations.

Consider an *invertible* square matrix $A$. $$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0&2\end{bmatrix}$$By definition, as an invertible matrix, this can be row-reduced to the identity matrix (obvious in this case). To see that the original and the reduced matrix are not equivalent, note that the *determinant* of $A$ is $4$, whereas the determinant of $I = 1$.

Comment: I understand that its not exactly the same matrix but that row-equivalence, doesn't it ensure that the linear system we started with is not at all changed and thus that the row reduced matrix can be used instead of the one we started with?

Comment: What *is* true is that a system of equations, when represented by an augmented coefficient matrix, and then row-reduced, the row reduced system of equations is equivalent to the original system of equations. But a square matrix, in and of itself, does not represent a system of equations.

Answer (score 0):

#### Counterexample:

Note that
$$
A = \pmatrix{
1&1&0\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&1
}
$$
Can be reduced to the identity.  Taking $b = \pmatrix{2\\2\\1}$
We note that the unique solution to 
$Ax = b$ is given by $x = \pmatrix{1\\1\\1}$.  Replacing $A$ with $I$, however, would give us the equality $x = b$, which is not the case.